# Android listview groups

Tags: android, listview

I have Activity for displaying search results. It extends ListActivity. I need to show search results in listview grouping several items. So, how do I add grouping to my listview?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You give your `ListView` a `ListAdapter` that knows how to do the grouping.

This could be a matter of overriding `getViewTypeCount()` and `getItemViewType()` in the adapter to describe which positions get which sorts of rows, plus modifying `getView()` (or `newView()` and `bindView()` for `CursorAdapter`) as needed.

Depending on what you are starting with, you might be able to use something like my [`MergeAdapter`](http://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-merge) instead.