# how to create listview with categories/segments?

Tags: android, listview

i want to create listview in android with following scenario

Heading Category 1

item 1
item 2
item 3

Heading Category 2

item 1
item 2

Heading Category 3
item 1

and so on.

any one guide me how to achieve this?
any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

A part of the answer is there : http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/index.html

see also there : [Android listview groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3962656/android-listview-groups)

Answer (score 1):

I believe [android.app.ExpandableListActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ExpandableListActivity.html) is what you are looking for. Check out this sample: `samples/android-9/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/ExpandableList3.java` in your Android SDK.