# Android :How can i make a list of events day wise.?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am working in android.  I want to show a list of events. I can make this list using listView.

But i want to add Day just before the list of events. Means i have two arrayList

1. for Name of days
2. for name of events for a day

So please suggest me how can i implement this.? you can provide me link related this topic or give a code help.

I need like this  :---
[image]

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I would have a look at the suggestions below some of the earlier similar questions, like [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4545315/how-to-create-listview-with-categories-segments) and [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3962656/android-listview-groups).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either use **Sectioned ListView**(You have to customize ListView) or **Expandable ListView**(inbuilt).

Sectioned ListView examples:

- [Android – Sectioned Headers in ListViews](http://w2davids.wordpress.com/android-sectioned-headers-in-listviews/) ,
- [ListView Tips & Tricks #2: Section your ListView](http://android.cyrilmottier.com/?p=440)

Expandable ListView examples:

- [ExpandableListView on Android](http://techdroid.kbeanie.com/2010/09/expandablelistview-on-android.html)
- [Steps to implement ExpandableListView in android](http://about-android.blogspot.com/2010/04/steps-to-implement-expandablelistview.html) - Check the Step - 2 in this example, same way groups[] and children[][], you can implement your 2 arraylists accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [SimpleAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleAdapter.html) and bind the Name of the days to one TextView and the event name to another TextView. Your xml layout will then just be a LinearLayout, oriented horizontally, with two TextViews in it. Here's an [example](http://mylifewithandroid.blogspot.com/2008/03/my-first-meeting-with-simpleadapter.html).