# How can I perform selective highlighting of elements when clicking an Android ListView row?

Tags: android, android-listview

I implemented alphabetical section headers in my ListView by adding an additional `TextView` element in my `ListView` row layout and using this additional `TextView` element as the header by toggling it's `setVisibility` property when necessary in my custom CursorAdapter. So my row layout hierarchy consists of 2 `TextView`'s inside a vertical `LinearLayout`.

I want the section headers to be independent of the row element it's contained in.

Originally, clicking on the header would perform the action of the row element it's contained in, so for example if my list consisted of the elements 'Apple' 'Apricot' and 'Avocado', clicking on the header, which is labeled as 'A' would perform whatever action of the row it's attached to, which in this example would be 'Apple'. I managed to prevent this from happening by setting the `TextView` representing the header as clickable.

However, I am still stuck with an annoying visual effect where when I click on 'Apple', the highlighting showing my selection on click highlights the entire row, so both `TextView`'s are highlighted. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uom2Z.png) is an example showing what I mean. In this example, when I click 'Daft Punk', the attached header 'D' is also highlighted. Is there anyway to set it so that only the second `TextView` is highlighted?

Answer (score 0):

That isn't supported in a non-hacky way. If you want to properly implement a listview with sections, there's a plethora of examples using the supported multiple view types strategy.

Here are two questions for implementations and libs that do what you want:

[Android listview groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3962656/android-listview-groups)
[Creating categories in a ListView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1013765/creating-categories-in-a-listview)

A tutorial to roll your own:

http://w2davids.wordpress.com/android-sectioned-headers-in-listviews/

If you do want to go the hacky route, in the comments for this post, he mentions intercepting touch by exploiting the focus/click event behavior bug. 
[Cyril Mottier](http://cyrilmottier.com/2011/07/05/listview-tips-tricks-2-section-your-listview/)